# Call class one after another. Once First one is finished

Tags: apex, process-builder

[image]

I am calling this class from a process builder. This class **ZEBMergeCase** will be called twice simulataniously with two differnt Case Id. Inside this class I am calling another queable class **UpdateParentAccount** which will be also called twice with two inputs. My field **Case_Merged_From__c** is blank initially, so for the first time it will go and it should updated the field so, that when 2nd time **UpdateParentAccount** runs, It should go in ELSE condition but, actually it goes to first If condition 2nd time also. That is why I wnted that if somehow my 2nd time call should wait once first time it finish up.

```
 public class ZEBMergeCase {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void updateMasterField(List<String> MergeCaseField)
    {
        String mergecase;
        String casenumber;
        System.debug('MergeCaseField=='+MergeCaseField);
        Case c = [Select Id,Case_Merged_To__c,CaseNumber from Case where Id in:MergeCaseField];
        System.debug('c===='+c);
        mergecase=c.Case_Merged_To__c.left(8);
        casenumber=c.CaseNumber;
        UpdateParentAccount updateJob = new UpdateParentAccount(mergecase, casenumber);
        ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(updateJob);
    }


    public class UpdateParentAccount implements Queueable {
        private String m;
        private String c;

        public UpdateParentAccount(String m, String c) {
            this.m = m;
            this.c = c;
        }
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
            Case c1 = [Select Id,Case_Merged_From__c,CaseNumber from Case where casenumber=:m];
            if(c1.Case_Merged_From__c == null)
            {
                c1.Case_Merged_From__c = c;
            }
            else
            {
                c1.Case_Merged_From__c = c1.Case_Merged_From__c+','+c;
            }
            update c1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It always goes to the first 'If'. I am calling it from process builder and it will be called twice with different inputs. So, class 'UpdateParentAccount' is called 2 times and field Case_Merged_From__c doesn't get updated and it gets called again.

Comment: Can I suggest you provide details of the process builder flow (screenshots etc.) as part of your question, because as it stands it does not contain the relevant and important information. Do this by editing the question, not by adding comments.

Comment: Sure, I am doing that. @Phil W

Comment: Please let me know, If you need any more details.....Thanks

Comment: I have added all the relevant information. Please remove the down votes so, that if anyone interested then they can help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to me to be a confusion about the order of operations and how Asynchronous Apex works, although I'm not entirely sure that I understand how and when this Invocable Method is being called.

The key is the fact that your Invocable Method fires a Queueable. When you invoke any form of Asynchronous Apex, it doesn't start running immediately - you're not spawning a thread. Rather, the Asynchronous Apex job is enqueued in the context of your current transaction. When the transaction completes successfully, the async job is persisted to the queue in the database.

The platform will run jobs from the queue as resources are available. There's no SLA for how long that will take. However, one thing *is* guaranteed: they won't run until the spawning transaction has completed.

So let's say you have this Process that fires twice in a transaction. On the first run, your Invocable Method will enqueue a Queueable. That Queueable sits in the queue. On the second run, your Invocable Method will enqueue another Queueable. That Queueable also sits in the queue.

Then the transaction ends successfully. Both Queueables are now in the queue waiting for system processing. Critically, **you have no guarantee or control over when they execute**. They may even run simultaneously, resulting in a race condition when they both try to update the same object in the same way.

It's hard for me to see here what exactly you're trying to do (or indeed why you need a Queueable in the first place), so I won't make any specific recommendations about how to fix the problem. But generally, the two things you should consider in refactoring are

1. Queueable chains. If you have multiple operations that need to be done sequentially and in separate transaction contexts, you should spawn only one Queueable, which then [chains into](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm) a second Queueable. In that circumstance, you can guarantee order of operations.
2. [Apex locking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_locking_statements.htm). If you have multiple asynchronous jobs running that affect the same object, you should be locking the records that you are working on with the `FOR UPDATE` SOQL clause. This ensures that you do not have a race condition where Queueable A grabs the record to make a change, then Queueable B also grabs the record without seeing Queueable A's updates.

All that said, I do wonder whether this is an X-Y problem, because I really see no reason to use Asynchronous Apex here at all. However, the code itself does not make a lot of sense - no merge is taking place, and no parent account is being updated.

Comment: Is _they won't run until the spawning transaction has completed_ documented somewhere?

Comment: @identigral I'm actually not sure that's explicitly documented, but the fact that enqueuing asynchronous Apex is transactional is pretty easy to validate (throw an exception after enqueuing; the enqueuing is rolled back).

Comment: The process builder is being called when I am merging 3 records using standard lightning merge button. The record Id that is passed from process builder is of the two looser record. I didn't wanted to complicate it so didn't inform this situation. I know about apex chaining but how can we implement here since for the second job I need to pass the input?

Comment: If I used the update statement in normal method other than queable. I am getting dml exception at merge that I am trying to make update from standard merge but the apex class is also trying to update.

Comment: I'm still slightly fuzzy on the overall flow of operations, although I think I have a rough sense. It sounds like you need to be using `FOR UPDATE` to lock the records each time through the Queueable.

Comment: Yes correct @David

Comment: Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you asking? Your last comment made me believe you agreed with my recommendation.

Comment: Can you put some example..I am not sure how exactly you are saying to lock the record@David?

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the documentation link in the body of my answer.

Comment: Okay  thanks for the help